# node.js or v8 garbage collector logging

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, garbage-collection, v8

I'm working on tracking down memory leaks in our node.js application, and I've been messing with things like node --trace-gc. But I'm curious if there's some node compile options or other tricks to make node log out not just what its doing in the garbage collection, but what references its marking, sweeping, and compacting. Knowing what these references are would help us identify things that are still being marked as reachable, especially when we're not expecting them to be.

I've looked for clues in node.js's documentation, but didn't find much. I usually get close to an answer on a lot of good blog posts, but my next step is downloading the code and doing some reading.

### Update

I've been using heap diffs from https://www.npmjs.com/package/memwatch#heap-diffing. Kind of useful, but still lacking. I have a string *somewhere* leaking:

```js
{ before: 
   { nodes: 144924,
     time: Tue Apr 12 2016 17:56:57 GMT+0000 (UTC),
     size_bytes: 16739240,
     size: '15.96 mb' },
  after: 
   { nodes: 177032,
     time: Tue Apr 12 2016 18:22:37 GMT+0000 (UTC),
     size_bytes: 25575708,
     size: '24.39 mb' },
  change: 
   { size_bytes: 8836468,
     size: '8.43 mb',
     freed_nodes: 1357,
     allocated_nodes: 33465,
     details: 
      [ { '+': 1,
          what: 'Arguments',
          size_bytes: 0,
          size: '0 bytes',
          '-': 1 },
        { '+': 296,
          what: 'Array',
          size_bytes: 12312,
          size: '12.02 kb',
          '-': 263 },
        { '+': 4,
          what: 'Closure',
          size_bytes: 36,
          size: '36 bytes',
          '-': 3 },
        { '+': 41,
          what: 'Code',
          size_bytes: 26144,
          size: '25.53 kb',
          '-': 4 },
        { '+': 2, what: 'Date', size_bytes: 0, size: '0 bytes', '-': 2 },
        { '+': 1, what: 'Native', size_bytes: 0, size: '0 bytes', '-': 1 },
        { '+': 4, what: 'Number', size_bytes: 0, size: '0 bytes', '-': 4 },
        { '+': 112,
          what: 'Object',
          size_bytes: -932,
          size: '-932 bytes',
          '-': 159 },
        { '+': 1,
          what: 'SlowBuffer',
          size_bytes: 0,
          size: '0 bytes',
          '-': 1 },
        { '+': 32974,
          what: 'String',
          size_bytes: 8797164,
          size: '8.39 mb',
          '-': 910 },
        [length]: 10 ] } }
```

Comment: If you are looking for space leaks, diffing heap snapshots tends to be the way most memory profilers do it.

Comment: there are a lot more flags. youtube has some good videos about such profiling.

Comment: Like DanD said, I think you want to be taking heap snapshots and then diffing them.  That will show you what was added to the heap and you can review that to see if anything is persisting that should not.

Comment: Yeah, good idea on the heap diff. I'm going to see if https://github.com/lloyd/node-memwatch#heap-diffing exposes my issues, kind of missed that section before.

Comment: So I got heap diffs working well, although I had to cross compile the library for my ARM device. But I'm getting a lot of leaks from what I think are our node bindings (CPP code using v8), which the JS accounting looses reference to. GC logging would still be awesome for this.